# Automatic drop-in replacement of HTML POST forms with XHR POSTs?

Tags: javascript, forms, post, xmlhttprequest

By using XHR to POST a form, one gets quite a few benefits - progress updates and the like.

I would like to hack together a way to 'upgrade' my regular POST forms to use XHR *by overrifing onsubmit, i guess). The XHR code would then post to the same action URL as the regular form. As far as I can see, this should work, and should automatically degrade to regular POST submits.

My question is if this is feasible, and how I can show the server's response to the POST to the user. Maybe setting the 's innerHTML wo the server response? Then I would have to massage the URL and location?

Has this been done in vanillaJS?

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly feasible. Although usually only a partial of the new page is returned when the request was done with XHR. Ajax requests are often flagged with the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` HTTP header.

Comment: But my plan is not even modify the server code, so the server should be returning a complete HTML document, as if it received a regular POST, correct?

Comment: If you want a 'drop-in replacement' that achieves that you're gonna have a hard time, and probably create a load of overhead. Go with minimal updates to the DOM, otherwise there is no point in doing XHR anyway.